# How to split an HTML container if it contains a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to find out if there are other `<div>` or `<iframe>` elements in my current `<div>`, and separate them from other data. For example, I need to transfer HTML from this:

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Some text<p>

  <iframe src="test.com"/>

  <p>Other text<p>
</div>
```

to this

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Some text<p>
</div>

<iframe src="test.com"/>

<div class="main">
  <p>Other text<p>
</div>
```

Also, the element that needs to be removed from the `<div>` may be at the end, so it will be enough to move the closing `</div>` tag in front of it instead of after it.

UPD:
I almost solved the problem, but one problem remained - how to embed ONLY the opening or closing tag in front or end of the element?

```
const splitter = function(element){
                let newObj = document.createElement("div");
                newObj.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
                [...newObj.querySelectorAll("div.typo")].forEach(ele => {
                 if(ele.querySelectorAll("div.incut").length != 0){
             ele.querySelectorAll("div.incut").forEach(eles => {
               eles.before('</div>') //here
               eles.after('<div class="typo">') //and here
               })
             }
            })
        console.log(newObj)
        };
```

console:

```
<div class="typo">
  <p>Some text</p>
  "</div>"<div class="incut"> Incut text</div>"<div class="typo">"
  <p>Other text</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you are certain element is nested in `main` you can use `element.removeChild()`, store it to variable then recreate in other element.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this using the available [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). What have you tried so far? Are there any constraints, e.g. does the `<div class="main">` need to be preserved in the DOM (otherwise it’d trigger MutationObservers and potentially lose its event listeners)?

Comment: @AdrianSolarczyk i need to insert  my cut element right between other elements in div, where i found it. So this is the problem...

Comment: @user4642212 all events listeners doesn't matter for me, so no, i can make 3 new elements instead of 1

Comment: Have you considered other options, e.g. CSS [`display: contents;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Box)?

Comment: @user4642212 Unfortunately no, I need to change the structure of DOM, not solve the visualization issue :(

Comment: Can there be multiple `<iframe>`s in the same `<div class="main">`?

Comment: @user4642212 yes. if there will be 2 iframes, the result in this case should be 3 div and 2 iframes between them (all div should have end at the place where the iframe starts, and have start where iframe end)

Comment: Go through the children of `<div class="main">` via `Array.from(document.querySelector("div.main").children)` (or even `.childNodes`), then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them to an array containing alternating element lists of _inside_ and _outside_ elements, discriminated by a [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Then, [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) and `append` etc. should be useful. Have you tried something like this?

Comment: @user4642212 in theory, everything seems to be clear. I'm not very friendly with the reduce function, but I'll try to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here are the steps:

1. Declare a temp variable `lastMain` which will be the last `.main` div so the elements in the "queue" will append to it. Also `isLastNodeIframe` to identify if need to create a new `.main`.
2. Iterate through all the elements.

   - If it's an iframe, you put it out with `parentNode.appendChild` into its parent.
   - If it's an empty string which caused by code indentation, ignore.
   - If it's not an `iframe`:

     - If the previous tag was `iframe`, re-create `.main`.
     - Append the child to `lastMain`.

```js
const app = document.querySelector('.app');
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
let lastMain;
let isLastNodeIframe = false;
Array.from(main.childNodes).forEach(child => {
  if (isIframe(child)) {
    isLastNodeIframe = true;    
    main.parentNode.appendChild(child);
  } else if (isEmptyText(child)) {
    return;
  } else {
    if (isLastNodeIframe) {
      isLastNodeIframe = false;
      lastMain = main.cloneNode(false);
      main.parentNode.appendChild(lastMain);
    }

    if (lastMain) {
      lastMain.appendChild(child);
    }
  }
});

function isIframe(element) {
  return element.tagName === 'IFRAME';
}

function isEmptyText(element) {
  return !element.tagName && !element.textContent.trim();
}

console.log(app.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="main">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <iframe></iframe>
    <p>Other text1</p>
    <p>Other text2</p>
    text without parent
    <iframe></iframe>
    <p>Other text3</p>
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

If something is not clear, let me know.

Comment: Careful, `main.querySelectorAll('*')` matches all descendants, not only children. I’d recommend `.childNodes` instead, so that Text nodes in between elements get considered as well (`.tagName` needs another condition then, e.g. `child.nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE`). Also, this puts an empty `<div class="main">` after an `<iframe>` if no other element follows it.

Comment: Tips taken. Thanks!

Comment: everything is great, thanks, but there is one remark - your code returns only the first element, I tried to modify it, because there can be several such elements on the page and they need to be processed all, but I did not succeed. I would be very grateful for the help

Comment: What do you mean by `first element`? Another `.main` elements? Please create a demo (using https://jsbin.com or https://codesandbox.io/ etc.) and I'll try to help with that.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uaj842qn/ There may be several <div> with class, `main` but your code returns only the first of them, i put a link :)

Comment: This was more challenging :) I ended up with: 1. Do the logic for each `.main`. 2. In order to isolate each `.main` (to not mess the order), each `.main` wrapped at the beginning and unwrapped after its children manipulation. https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/woL94k8u/25/

Comment: My pleasure. Don't hesitate to contact me through my channels (you can find them in my profile page) or tag me in future questions. Good luck!